# How to override properties of container div

Tags: html, css

I have a `p` tag inside which there is a `div` with content `-` When I use `padding-right:-9px;` for the `div` the `padding-left:10px;` of the `p` tag is no longer in effect.How can I overcome this situation?

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>
  <div id="id">-</div>TExT HeRe
</p>
```

and CSS:

```
#id
{
    padding-right:-9px;
    display:inline;
}
p
{
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: According to the CSS specifications, padding values cannot be negative.

Comment: I don't think divs in paragraphs is valid HTML.

Comment: that very basic of css, padding should never be negative. BTW , what are trying to do here

Comment: @anwerjunaid even when I put positive values also i get the same result

Comment: Also worth pointing out the rules of CSS specificity: https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/specificity-calculationbase.png

Comment: Depends on what are you looking for. **<p>** tag can only have inline tags, like **b**, **i** . Div is block tag .

Comment: Short version of CSS specificty: INLINE > ID > CLASS > ELEMENT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because this:

```
<p>
  <div id="id">-</div>TExT HeRe
</p>
```

being invalid HTML, is most likely actually being rended as such:

```
<p></p>
<div id="id">-</div>TExT HeRe
```

I would suggest using a `span` element rather than a `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is semantically incorrect: you should not have a `<p>` element with a div on the inside; it is better to use `<span>`. How I would tackle this is to place your `<p>` inside a `<div>` and a `<span>` inside your `<p>`. In addition give your `<div>` a position, width, and height.

```css
<style>
#div_1 {
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: pink;
 }
#id {
 padding-right: -9px;
 display: block;
 background-color: cyan;
 width: 50px;
 position: relative;
 
 }
p {
 padding-left: 10px;
 
 }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div_1">
 <p>
 <span id="id">-</span>TexT HeRe
 </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure as I'm not so good with CSS but I've seen things such as this being used which may possibly be what you're looking for?

```
<style>
#id{
base css
}
#id > p{
any paragraph within the id div will get these properties
}
</style>
```